# assigning different names for each test to store user inputs and accessing it

Tags: java

The first line will consists of one integer T denoting the number of test cases.

For each test case:

1. The first line consists of two integers N and K, N being the number of elements in the array and K denotes the number of steps of rotation.
2. The next line consists of N space separated integers , denoting the elements of the array A.

Sample input

```
1
5 2
1 2 3 4 5
```

sample output

```
4 5 1 2 3
```

My code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int test=scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
        int size;
        int steps;
        int temp=0;
        for(int j=1;j<=test;j++){
        ArrayList<Integer> array+j = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        size = scan.nextInt();
        steps = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
           array+j.add(scan.nextInt());
        }
        
        
        for(int i=0;i<steps;i++){
           
            temp = array+j.get(size-1);
            array+j.remove(size-1);
            array+j.add(0,temp);
            
        }

        if(j==test){
            for(j=1;j<=test;j++){
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        System.out.print(array+j.get(i)+" ");
        }
        }
        }

        }

        
        
    }
}
```

This program has Error cause we can not assign different names like

```
 for(int j=1;j<=test;j++){
 ArrayList<Integer> array+j = new ArrayList<Integer>();
}
```

So, how can i achive this

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: yes, my program has error

Answer (score 1):

Is this answer your question ?

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int T = scanner.nextInt(); // read test cases

    while (T-- > 0) {
        int N = scanner.nextInt(); // read number of integers
        int K = scanner.nextInt(); // read number of permutations

        int[] array = new int[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            array[i] = scanner.nextInt(); // store numbers in array
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[(N - K + i) % N] + " "); // print element N - K as the first element
        }
        System.out.println(); // return to new line after each test case
    }
    scanner.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope, let us assume first input as 3 than, the program should ask three times the test case which is array size and rotation and another line which is array's element, than at last it print all three arrays element simultaneously with rotation.

Comment: can you explain more ?

Comment: yeah i edited please see comment again, thanks

Comment: actually i tried to achieve this with this code.

      ```  ArrayList<Integer> array[] = new ArrayList[test];```

Comment: I should show you full code if you want but it shows null pointer exception.

Comment: why to store data if you want just to display the output ? is this a competitive programming problem ?

Comment: 2
5 2
1 2 3 4 5
5 3
1 2 3 4 5

Comment: run the program with this input and you can see the result, it's print for each test case to rotation of the array

Comment: yes it is competitive programming and as you know in what way they say we have to take input and print output in that way only we have to write program,

Comment: Did you have the solution please tell me if you have.

Comment: did you try the solution that i have published ?

Comment: Yes, I tried but that was not working like what question wants as i explained. I already created program like this this program is running but not the case of question as i explained before.